# How to remove default margin in angular app?

Tags: css, angular

Very simple app.component.html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sub"/>
```

The result of the code above

[image]

How to remove margin arround the button? I want the button is located on the top left without indent.

Comment: Check your css on the `html` and `body` tags, see if they have a padding etc. Without your html/css, can't help you.

Comment: its most prob the parent container, you would have to post the container code, F12 > developer tools > inspect, there will be padding on the container.

Comment: Go to your `AppComponent.css` or to your `style.css` file and look for paddings or margins, just remove them and your good to go

Comment: David, ty for your simple help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why does angular use what default padding?

Problem resolved!

I added this code in the global styles:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: If you generated the app with the Angular CLI, it just sets some default styling for the index page to get you started, nothing that can't be removed; if this is what you did I'd recommend you accept it as the answer since the other response is not what you used

Answer (score 16):

Use in app.component.scss

```css
 ::ng-deep * {
      
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Comment: why isn't this the accepted answer, works like a charm

Comment: Exactly its the simple and best answer @LeeM....Thanks Waldo !!

Comment: Excelent answer, this is what i was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You have to go to the styles.css of the proyect and write 
`body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}`
and that's it, it's simple Hope it works, this was the way I solved the problem

Comment: how is it different from an existing acceptedd answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix it at top left forcefully without removing any margin padding in container. 
Add style to it 
position:fixed;top: 0;left: 0;
Or 
set html, body{ padding: 0px;margin: 0px;} in your style.css file

Comment: I'd definitely woudn't recommend setting a `position:fixed` just to remove margins and paddings

Comment: I have mentioned that use position fixed only when you want forcefully that button at top left position.

Comment: I understand, I'm just saying that it's not an optimal solution, since, in any case, if you want to *forcefully* remove the margins and paddings, you can set `margin: 0px !important` or `padding: 0px !important`, which isn't a good practice as well, but at least avoids setting a position property on an element, which may cause more issues down the line

Answer (score -1):

That is not from angular, it is added by browser.
You have to [reset css](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)